# How to build and install yajl-objc on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, yajl

Hey I am trying to get http://github.com/gabriel/yajl-objc to work on iOS. It says to "Add the YAJLIOS.framework to your project" but I am not sure how I can get/build YAJLIOS.framework

Thanks!
-Ray

Comment: If you're planning on submitting your app to the App Store, be aware that you can't use private frameworks... your app will be rejected.

Comment: You are allowed to static compile libraries against your application.

Answer (score 4):

Although this is an old question, I came across the issue today updating a client's old project. The YAJL-objC project requires you to run a makefile command in order to compile the .framework file needed for installation.

To create the framework, checkout the latest from [github](https://github.com/gabriel/yajl-objc), and then open Terminal. Change your directory to: `yajl-objc\Project-iOS`

Next, type the command `make` and run it. This will execute the compiling for you and create a new framework file here: `yajl-objc\Project-iOS\Framework\YAJLiOS.framework`

You can then drag that framework into the project you wish to use it in. Good luck!

Comment: Hi, I am trying to do as you described but there is no \Project-iOS folder under yajl-objc. Maybe I am doing something wrong? I just downloaded zip file from github - it appears as yajl-objc-master in my Downloads folder. But there is no \Project-iOS folder under yajl-objc-master.

Answer (score 0):

I should have looked harder, but there is simply a download under the github download link that includes the framework.